# Passing a Javascript object to PHP without creating a query string

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, phpspreadsheet

I have an HTML table on the front-end *(back-end doesn't have the data)* and there's a button to export the table into an Excel spreadsheet using [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). Currently when clicking the button, a script parses the table and builds an object with all the header and data so that I can pass this to a PHP script and then the library will take care of creating the Excel file afterwards.

My approach uses AJAX but I keep getting errors because the library changes the Content Type.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.export-btn', function() {
  let parsed = {
    header: [],
    data: []
  };
  
  ... // build the object from the table
  
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'export.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: parsed,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) { ... },
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR) { ... },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }
  });
});
```

**export.php:**

```php
... // build the spreadsheet

# Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Xlsx)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

# If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

# If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');                # Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');   # always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate');                 # HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');                                        # HTTP/1.0

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');

$spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($spreadsheet);
```

With the table being large, I don't think I can do a simple redirect to `export.php` with the data passed as a query string.

Comment: `dataType: "json",` is what you are 'expecting back'. I don't think you want json returned, since it should be building a spreadsheet stream back (which you'll need to figure out how to then give the user in the ajax success return... which, I'm unsure is possible? surely it is, I've never done it though lol).

Comment: You may have to resort to storing the spreadsheet temporarily on the server and passing back a download link, which then the ajax will use to pop up a lil-window to the location of to cause the browser to download it. But then you may need a cleanup script later to get rid of all the temp spreadsheets on the server.